# Using both watchdog timers in PIC

Tags: pic, sleep, watchdog

I want to use both the conventional WDT and deep sleep WDT.

1. I will be using WDT to prevent any code lock cases if any.
2. And the other after entering deep sleep mode to wake up periodically in deep sleep mode.

My question is whether the WDT will continue working after entering deep sleep and intervene the DSWDT if not disabled?

I'm using PIC18 controllers.

Comment: I am not sure that I have understood what you are really asking here. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you are asking:

"if i put my device in deep sleep mode will the WDT wake it up (or possibly reset it) because the micro controller is not clearing the register?"

The answer to this question is: who knows? PIC18 is a family and not a device, so I can't read the datasheet because I don't know what device you are referring to.

Anyway I am quite sure that when in deep sleep the main WDT would be disabled, or else I don't see why you should have another WDT to wake it up. Moreover, you can disable it for sure before going in deep sleep mode and re-enable it just after the device is woken up.

Please note that probably WDT and DSWDT share some hardware so it might even be *impossible* to have them working simultaneously.